# error in compilation gwt

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc, gxt

i have gwt application when i compile there is many error

Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
   Finding entry point classes
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/D:/environnement_pfe/GridBindingExample/src/com/sencha/gxt/client/GridBindingExample.java'
         [ERROR] Line 45: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.examples.resources.client.model.Stock; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 45: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.examples.resources.client.model.TestData; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 59: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.explorer.client.binding.StockEditor; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 66: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.FramedPanel; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 68: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.Grid; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 69: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.data.client.editor.ListStoreEditor; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 84: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.VerticalLayoutContainer; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 86: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.examples.resources.client.model.StockProperties; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 88: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.ColumnConfig; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 92: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.data.shared.ListStore; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 92: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.ColumnModel; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 93: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.core.client.Style.SelectionMode; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 98: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.VerticalLayoutContainer.VerticalLayoutData; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 99: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.selection.SelectionChangedEvent.SelectionChangedHandler; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 101: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.selection.SelectionChangedEvent; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 112: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.event.SelectEvent.SelectHandler; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 115: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.event.SelectEvent; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 120: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.core.client.util.Margins; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Unable to find type 'com.sencha.gxt.client.GridBindingExample'
         [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
         [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly

Comment: file XML:

 <module rename-to='gridbindingexample'>
                    
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

                        
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
                       
  <entry-point class='com.sencha.gxt.client.GridBindingExample'/>

 
  <source path='client'/>

  <source path='server'/>



</module>

Answer (score 1):

Are the dependencies to GXT included in the `gwt.xml` file? If you are not sure you can have a look here: [getting started with gxt](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt-guides/3/getting_started/getting_started_3/Getting_Started_3.html)

If you want to include a module created to use in your gwt application, you have to provide some important information to the gwt compiler. For example the gxt is such a library and the gwt compiler has to compile the sources for the client side to javascript. If the compiler does not know something about the "extra packages" he can not compile the javascript...

You have to include a line simliar like this in your *project*.gwt.xml:

```
<inherits name='foo.bar.3rdPartyModule' />
```

In case of Gxt:

```
<inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT' />
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Okay, you are right! But this was only a guess, because the stacktrace itself is not enough information to give the right answer...